# 0-1 Knapsack in Java

Tags: java, interview-questions, dynamic-programming

I'm looking for advice on coding practices in general.

```
 public class Knapsack {

        public static int getMaxBenefit(int[] weights, int[] benefits, int capacity) {

        int[][] maxbenefit = new int[weights.length + 1][capacity + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= weights.length; i++)
            maxbenefit[i][0] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= capacity; i++)
            maxbenefit[0][i] = 0;

        for (int item = 1; item <= weights.length; item++) {

            for (int weight = 1; weight <= capacity; weight++) {

                if (weights[item - 1] <= weight) {

                    int option1 = benefits[item - 1] + maxbenefit[item - 1][weight - weights[item - 1]];
                    int option2 = maxbenefit[item - 1][weight];
                    maxbenefit[item][weight] = Math.max(option1, option2);

                } else {
                    maxbenefit[item][weight] = maxbenefit[item - 1][weight];
                }

            }

            // printMatrix(maxbenefit, weights.length, capacity);
        }

        printMatrix(maxbenefit, weights.length, capacity);

        return maxbenefit[weights.length][capacity];
    }

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix, int R, int C) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= R; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= C; j++) {

                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " | ");

            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] weights = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] benefit = new int[] { 3, 4, 8, 9, 9 };
        getMaxBenefit(weights, benefit, 5);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    int[][] maxbenefit = new int[weights.length + 1][capacity + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= weights.length; i++)
        maxbenefit[i][0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= capacity; i++)
        maxbenefit[0][i] = 0;
```

There is no need to initialize part of the array as 0, because the entire array starts off as 0.

```
public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix, int R, int C) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= R; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= C; j++) {

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " | ");

        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

In here, you should check if `R` and `C` don't exceed `matrix.length` and `matrix[i].length` respectively. That way you can either limit the printing, or you could throw an error with explanation, rather than running into `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

In the same way, you should check the size of `int[] benefits` in `getMaxBenefit`, because if the weights and the benefits are not the same size then you'll throw an error at some point, and failing fast is better.